# wp_dropdown_pages doesn't work with post_type argument

Tags: custom-post-types, dropdown

I'm trying to display dropdown menu with posts with custom "post_type".

In case I insert this code, it shows dropdown menu with all "pages".

```
$arg=array(
            'show_option_none' => __( 'None' ),
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'suppress_filters' => true
        );

        wp_dropdown_pages($arg);
```

But in case I insert this code, it doesn't show nothing, neither dropdown menu at all.

```
$arg=array(
            'show_option_none' => __( 'None' ),
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'post_type'=>'custom_post_type',
            'suppress_filters' => true
        );

        wp_dropdown_pages($arg);
```

Thanks for any advice!!

WordPress 3.9.2, PHP 5.5.1

Comment: The name of your custom post type is 'custom_post_type'?

Comment: No. The name of my custom post type is 'events'. But it doesn't matter. But if I use any post type (include default 'post') it doesn't work. Just if I use 'post_type' argument it's not working.

Comment: Is your post type hierarchical?

Comment: Yep, that was problem! My post_type wan't hierarchical.
After set 'hierarchical' => true, it works!
Thank you Steven Jones.

Answer (score 9):

As answered by Steven Jones in the comments, I just want to confirm that the key thing is to specify your **custom post type's** settings to be `'hierarchical' => true`, not the `hierarchical` argument in `wp_dropdown_pages` function.

If you are using a custom plugin like Types or CPT UI, just set the option to true.